# scanf Getting Skipped

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to make a simple C program for a class and one of the requirements is that I'm required to use `scanf`/`printf` for all input and output. My question is why is it that my `scanf` after the for loop in the main gets skipped and the program just terminates.

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    int userValue;
    int x;
    char c;

    printf("Enter a number : ");
    scanf("%d", &userValue);
    printf("The odd prime values are:\n");
    for (x = 3; x <= userValue; x = x + 2) {
        int a;
        a = isPrime(x);
        if (a = 1) { 
            printf("%d is an odd prime\n", x);
        }
    }   
    printf("hit anything to terminate...");
    scanf("%c", &c);    
}

int isPrime(int number) {
    int i;
    for (i = 2; i < number; i++) {
        if (number % i == 0 && i != number)
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

I was able to "fix" it by adding another identical `scanf` after the first one, but I would prefer to just use the one.

Comment: Have you tried `system("PAUSE");`?

Comment: is that available in straight C or only C++?

Comment: Staight c. Notice the lack of a namespace?

Comment: ChatGPT:
```
// Clear the input stream
char c;
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n');
```
It works fine for me and it kinda makes sense.  
Or you can check for the number or assignments made by `scanf`:
```c
while (scanf("%c%x", &cmd, &loc) != 2);
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The new-line character present in `stdin` after the previous `int` was entered will not have been consumed by the last call to `scanf()`. So the call to `scanf()` after the `for` loop consumes the new-line character and continues without the user having to enter anything.

To correct without having to add another `scanf()` call you could use format specifier `" %c"` in the `scanf()` after the `for` loop. This will make `scanf()` skip any leading whitespace characters (including new-line). Note it means the user will have to enter something other than a new-line to end the program.

Additionally:

- check the result of `scanf()` to ensure it actually assigns a value to the variables passed in:

  ```
  /* scanf() returns number of assigments made. */
  if (scanf("%d", &userValue) == 1)
  ```
- this is an assignment (and will always be true):

  ```
  if (a = 1){ /* Use == for equality check.
                 Note 'a' could be removed entirely and
                 replace with: if (isPrime(x)) */
  ```

Comment: Why would it not have been consumed by the last call to `scanf()`? Sorry newb question

Comment: @SSHThis, `scanf("%d")` stops consuming when encounters something that is not a digit, and a new-line is not a digit so it will remain.

Comment: thanks for catching that mistake

Comment: Thank you, should it be `scanf("%d\n", &userValue);`?

Comment: @SSHThis, yes. That would work also.

Comment: Or use C++ with `std::cin`

Comment: `char temp; scanf("%c", &temp)`