# Simple Calculator in C flow of input skipping over scanf()

Tags: c, control-flow

I have tried to write my first calculator, and found some examples online, which I then changed to make them easier in terms of flow. However when I change the flow from this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    char operator;
    float num1,num2;

    printf("Enter an operator (+, -, *, /): ");
    scanf("%c" ,&operator);
    printf("Enter first operand: ");
    scanf("%f" ,&num1);
    printf("Enter second operand: ");
    scanf("%f" ,&num2); 

    switch(operator)
    {
        case '+':
            printf("num1+num2=%.2f\n" ,num1+num2);
            break;
        case '-':
            printf("num1-num2=%.2f\n" ,num1-num2);
            break;
        case '*':
            printf("num1*num2=%.2f\n" ,num1*num2);
            break;
        case '/':
            printf("num1/num2=%.2f\n" ,num1/num2);
            break;
        default: //of operator is other than +, -, *, /, erros message shown
        printf("Error! Invalid operator, this is basic math only.\n");
    }       
    return 0;
}
```

to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    char operator;
    float num1,num2;


    printf("Enter first operand: ");
    scanf("%f" ,&num1);
    printf("Enter an operator (+, -, *, /): ");
    scanf("%c" ,&operator);
    printf("Enter second operand: ");
    scanf("%f" ,&num2); 

    switch(operator)
    {
        case '+':
            printf("num1+num2=%.2f\n" ,num1+num2);
            break;
        case '-':
            printf("num1-num2=%.2f\n" ,num1-num2);
            break;
        case '*':
            printf("num1*num2=%.2f\n" ,num1*num2);
            break;
        case '/':
            printf("num1/num2=%.2f\n" ,num1/num2);
            break;
        default: //of operator is other than +, -, *, /, erros message shown
        printf("Error! Invalid operator, this is basic math only.\n");
    }       
    return 0;
}
```

basically changed the flow from: enter operator, then enter first number, then second number. To: enter first number, then enter operator, then enter second number. 
My problem is when I do this, I see the Enter operator, but the program skips over the option to enter the operator and asks for: enter first number then enter second number. The response is the default switch.

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484431/scanf-getting-skipped?rq=1) question?

Answer (score 0):

The newline you enter after `scanf` reads in your first operator is being taken by the second `scanf` calls. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484431/scanf-getting-skipped?rq=1) question for a more detailed explanation.

In short, write a function like this, and call it after every `scanf` call.

```
void clear_stdin(void)
{
    while(getchar() != '\n');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's because the newline character stays in the buffer when you enter the input of the first `scanf` , so the following `scanf` receive it as it's input , just put a `getchar()` after every `scanf()` that'll solve it

Answer (score 0):

New-line left in input buffer.

When using `scanf("%f",...`, the `%f` consume leading white-space, but no trailing white-spaces after the number - usually the `\n`.

When using `scanf("%c",...`, the `%c` does *not* consume leading white-space, and no trailing white-spaces after the `char` either.

To consume leftover white space (e.g. the `\n` from the previous `scanf()`), simple precede `%c` with a space.

```
// scanf("%c" ,&operator);
scanf(" %c" ,&operator);  // add space.
```

Comment: you are right this worked. what is the reason for this phenomenon? Is this an old bug in the c language or was this done purposefully and with a reason?

Comment: Assuming "this" in "Is this an old bug" refers to `%c` consuming whitespace: It is not a bug.  `%c` scans in 1 `char`, _any_ 1 `char`, no exceptions, including `' '`, `'\n'`, etc. and even `'\0'` (rarely encountered in reading text.)  To avoid scanning in whitespace, pre-pending the `' '` consumes all whitespace before `%c`.  Thus `" %c"` will not store a white space.  `%c` allows one to use `scanf()` to scan into a single `char` a space character.