# C - scanf gets skipped over (even with " %d")

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to figure out why I can't get this to run properly.  I just want four inputs from the user, and run the calculation at the end.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    double amount; /* amount on deposit */
    double principal; /* what's the principal */
    double rate; /* annual interest rate */
    int year; /* year placeholder and no. of total years */
    int yearNo;

    printf("What is the principal? ");
    scanf("%d", &principal);
    printf("What is the rate (in decimal)? ");
    scanf(" .2%d", &rate);
    printf("What is the principal? ");
    scanf(" %d", &principal);
    printf("How many years? ");
    scanf(" %d\n", yearNo);


    printf("%4s%21s\n", "Year", "Amount on deposit");

    /* calculate the amount on deposit for each of ten years */
    for (year = 1; year <= yearNo; year++){
        amount = principal * pow(1.0 + rate, year);
        printf("%4d%21.2f\n", year, amount);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It properly asks for the principal and rate, but then skips over the question about Principal and asks for years.  Then it just sits there waiting for a "ghost" entry?

I've been reading that the `scanf()` adds some whitespace when hitting `enter` but thought the space before the `%d` would fix that?

I also saw you could add `do { c=getchar(); } while ( c != '\n');` after each `scanf` but that seems to crash the program (I added `int c = 0;` to the beginning too).

Thanks for any help or ideas!

**EDIT:**

When I change the erroneous format specifier from:

```
scanf(" .2%d", &rate);
```

to:

```
scanf(" %d", &rate);
```

I then get a crash after entering my values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [scanf Getting Skipped](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484431/scanf-getting-skipped)

Comment: You're neglecting to check your return values.  In C that's a capital offense.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart - I tried the space before the %d and that isn't quite working.  Well, it may have fixed the issue with new line, but now it's crashing after I input my four values.

Comment: @user3718365 Sounds like a different problem.

Comment: @user3718365 A space before `"%d"` makes no difference on a successful scan into the `int`.   All format specifiers consume leading white space expect 3: `"%c"`, `"%n"`, `"%["`.

Comment: @user3718365, it's not usually a good idea to change the question in such a way that it renders answers (or, in this case, parts of answers) incorrect. I've modified it to show a more "acceeptable" way, simply adding the extra information as an addendum. That way, answers still make sense and you still manage to get extra info in that you need. In any case, the crash is caused by using a non-pointer in the scanf, see my updated answer for details.

Comment: @paxdiablo - thanks for that.  I'll remember this for the future, I'm still getting a hang of Stackoverflow and the proper etiquette, so thanks!

Comment: The `scanf()` for `principal` is broken; `principal` is a `double` so the format should be `"%lf"`.  See also [C &mdash; simple math argument not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28102910/c-simple-math-argument-not-working/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.2%d` is *not* a valid format string.

For a start, the `%` has to come first. In addition, if you're after a floating point value, `d` is not the right character - it's for *integral* values.

You should be using something like `%f` (you don't need width or precision modifiers).

On top of that, you've made a minor mistake of not using a *pointer* for one of your `scanf` calls:

```
scanf(" %d\n", yearNo);
```

That's probably going to cause a crash, and should be changed to:

```
scanf(" %d\n", &yearNo);
```

And, as a final suggestion, it's totally unnecessary to use whitespace before (or a newline after) `%d` or `%f` family of format specifiers. The scanner automatically skips whitespace before both of those.

So, the only two `scanf` format strings you *need* in this program are `"%d"` and `"%lf"` (`f` is for floats, `lf` is for doubles).

Comment: D'oh! ...I changed it to %f (so the rate is %f), I can now get all 4 lines inputted but after I enter the years, it crashes.

Comment: Ah, duh!  okay so hurray, now it works - only I get 0.00 as the amount every time it loops.

Comment: @user3718365, the crash is a different issue regarding pointers but I've added the solution to this answer.

Comment: Minor: `".2%d"` is not a valid format specifier yet is a valid format string.  IAC, certainly not what OP wanted.