# C - simple math argument not working?

Tags: c, math.h

I am just trying to calculate an amount for 10 years, using a relatively simple formula.  I can input all of my variables, but I suspect I'm doing something wrong with the `amount`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    double amount; /* amount on deposit */
    double principal; /* what's the principal */
    double rate; /* annual interest rate */
    int year; /* year placeholder and no. of total years */
    int yearNo;

    printf("What is the principal? ");
    scanf("%d", &principal);
    printf("What is the rate (in decimal)? ");
    scanf("%lf", &rate);
    printf("How many years? ");
    scanf("%d", &yearNo);

    printf("%4s%21s\n", "Year", "Amount on deposit");

    /* calculate the amount on deposit for each of ten years */
    for (year = 1; year <= yearNo; year++ ){
        amount = principal * pow(1.0 + rate, year);
        printf("%4d%21.2f\n", year, amount);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm new to C, but am following an example in a book. The book "hard codes" the numbers, where I'm trying to learn how to use the input from a user to calculate the data.

Am I right in thinking it's either my `amount` or how I refer to it with the `%f` at the end?

Thanks for any ideas :)

Comment: Enable all warnings - it will save you time: `scanf("%d", &principal);`

Comment: @chux - I will have to look into some kind of compiler - I'm using notepad++ and as far as I know there's no compiler for that.  I use GCC in the command line to compile so I will have to see how to check for errors before compiling. I use "gcc filename.c -o filename.exe" to compile.

Comment: Start with "gcc -Wall"

Answer (score 2):

With the `scanf()` family of functions, `%d` is for `int` but `%lf` is for `double`.

The first thing to do is to make sure you've got warnings turned on for your compiler.  Some compilers (GCC, Clang) report format errors like that.

The next thing to do is print the values you read.  When you see garbage coming out for the values you just read, you know there's a problem.

And after that, you check that the conversions succeeded:

```
if (scanf("%lf", &principal) != 1)
    …oops! input error or EOF…
```

Comment: Aha! It was the principal I wasn't considering.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's the inputs that are the problem — `scanf()`, as I noted in my edit just about the time your comment arrived.

Comment: I'll have to look in to a compiler. I'm using notepad++ with a simple command line with g++ to compile it (gcc filename.c -o filename.exe) and running the exe.

Comment: If you're using `g++`, then you're compiling with a C++ compiler.  However, you should be compiling with at least `-Wall` and preferably `-Wextra` too, and it would report the problems immediately (with just `-Wall`).  These options also work with `gcc`, though there are then other options that you might use too (but just `-Wall -Wextra` is a good start even there).