# the C program does not execute the function outside the main

Tags: c, system-calls

If I execute the exec() function in another C program as a main function it works perfectly, while if I put it as a function called in the main menu it gives me some warning and the function does not run.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h> /* for fork */
#include <sys/types.h> /* for pid_t */
#include <sys/wait.h> /* for wait */

int exec (void) {

        char array[100];
        char character;
        int i = 0;
        char* point;
        int j = 0;

        printf ("Digita una stringa");
        printf ("\n");
        do {
            character = getchar();
            array[i] = character;
            i++;
        }
        while (character != '\n');
        array[i-1] = '\0';
        i = 0;

        char* string[100];

        char *word = strtok(array, " .");
        j = 0;
        while (word != NULL) {
            printf("%s\n", word);
            string[j++] = word; // Increment j
            word = strtok(NULL, " .");
        }
        string[j] = NULL; // Make sure the array is NULL term

        printf ("\n");  

    pid_t  pid;
    pid = fork();
    int status;

    if (pid == -1) {
        perror("");
    }else if (pid == 0) {
        execvp(string[0], string);     /* execute the command  */
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to exec");  
                exit(1);
            }
    else {

        //.. wait until the child ends
        waitpid(-1, &status, 0);
      }

return;
}

int read_input (void) {
    int choice;
    printf("Seleziona una voce dal menu");
    do {    
        printf("\n");
        scanf ("%i", &choice);
        if (choice > 8 || choice < 1)
            printf ("Attenzione, inserisci un valore contemplato dal menu");
    }
    while ( choice > 8 || choice < 1);

return choice;
}

void main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    printf ("------------------------\n");
    printf ("          MENU         \n");
    printf ("------------------------\n");
    printf ("  \n");
    printf ("1) Esecuzione in foreground di un processo\n");
    printf ("2) Ctrl -C\n");
    printf ("3) Exit\n");
    printf ("4) Background\n");
    printf ("5) Pipe\n");
    printf ("6) Jobs\n");
    printf ("7) fg\n");
    printf ("8) kill\n");
    int menu = read_input();
    switch (menu) {

        case '1' :  
                exec ();
                break; 
        case '2' :
                //ctrl();
                break;
        case '3' :
                //exit_();
                break; 
        case '4' : 
                //background();
                break;
        case '5' :
                //pipe();
                break;
        case '6' : 
                //jobs();
                break;
        case '7' : 
                //fg();
                break;
        case '8' : 
                //kill();
                break;
    }
}
```

this is the warning:

```
elaborato.c:31:16: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default] char *word = strtok(array, " .");
```

Comment: > in the main menu it gives me some warning;
Could you be more precise which warning the compiler gives you.

Comment: yes. these are the warnings..                                                                              elaborato.c: In function ‘exec’:
elaborato.c:31:16: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
   char *word = strtok(array, " .");
                ^
elaborato.c:36:11: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
      word = strtok(NULL, " .");
           ^

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the problem related to input,

```
do {    
    printf("\n");
    scanf ("%i", &choice);
    if (choice > 8 || choice < 1)
        printf ("Attenzione, inserisci un valore contemplato dal menu");
}
while ( choice > 8 || choice < 1);
```

Once you type an integer and press enter, the `scanf()` consumes the number and a newline is left in stdin. Next time the loop goes around (assuming input <1 or >8 or something else) scanf gets that newline and it goes on.
add a `getchar()` after the `scanf()`.

Comment: that works perfectly and now I get why it didn't work before!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the warnings, you should move them from the comment into the question.

```
elaborato.c:31:16: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default] char *word = strtok(array, " .");
```

That means that `word`, which is a `char` pointer is being initialized from an integer.  Therefore, it seems `strtok()` is returning an integer... that doesn't sound right.

From the `strtok()` man page:

```
#include <string.h> 

char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim);

char *strtok_r(char *str, const char *delim, char **saveptr);
```

That seems right, it returns a `char *`.... but it also says it's declared in `<string.h>`... which you aren't including.  Since it's not defined, the compiler assumes it as `int strtok()`.

Fix: add the `#include <string.h>` line.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it fixed the warnings problem, but the function exec still not work.. I can't input a string, the program ends in the do while loop in the exec function..

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are seeing is that of `scanf` getting skipped.

For more details you can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484431/scanf-getting-skipped)

The call to `scanf()` after the `printf` consumes the new-line character and continues without the user having to enter anything.

It reads the very next character from standard in, which is probably a newline character and thus not prompting you for any input.

Comment: i can see now that the problem is when, in the exec() function, i tried to get the string input..now i run the program, the exec() function start running but ends immediately without letting me input the string. is getchar() the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm too tired to comment on the entire code (it is really bad), so I'll just write about the issue in question and how **trivially** it could be debugged.

First thing to do is to check if we get the number and return to main, hence:

```
int menu = read_input();
printf("got [%d]\n", menu);
```

Running this:

```
[snip]
1
got [1]
```

So we indeed get to this point.

As such now we check what is this compared to.

```
int menu = read_input();
printf("got [%d] '1'=[%d]\n", menu, '1');
```

Let's run:

```
1
got [1] '1'=[49]
```

So, **menu** stores an integer 1, while **'1'** is a character code for 1 in ascii, which, well, is not an integer 1.

In general I don't see what was the problem with narrowing it down.