# C for loop runs good first iteration only the next iteration it ignores scanf in loop

Tags: c

I'm trying to write calculator code in C for loop. The problem it runs good at first iteration only. the next iterations it ignores scanf command so it gives wrong output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
int i ;
char operator_;
double x, y;
for (i = 1; i <= 3; ++i)
{
printf("Enter an operator (+, -, *,/): ");
scanf("%c",&operator_);
printf("\nEnter the first number: ");
scanf("%lf",&x);
printf("Enter the second number: ");
scanf("%lf",&y);
switch (operator_) {
case '+':
printf("The sum equals to %lf + %lf = %lf\n\n\n", x, y, x + y);
break;
case '-':
printf("The difference equals to %lf - %lf = %lf\n\n\n", x, y, x - y);
break;
case '*':
printf("The product equals to %lf * %lf = %lf\n\n\n", x, y, x * y);
break;
case '/':
printf("The quotient equals to %lf / %lf = %lf\n\n\n", x, y, x / y);
break;
default:
printf("Error! operator is not correct\n\n\n");
}
}
printf("\nyour trial period has ended\n\n\n");
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scanf Getting Skipped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484431/scanf-getting-skipped)

Comment: Try: `scanf("%c",&operator_);` -> `scanf(" %c",&operator_);`. That is, add space before `%c`

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding (the compiler doesn't care)  Please consistently indent the code,.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each each indent level be 4 spaces,