# how to find sum of each value of column in multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, c

sorry, im still try to figure out about multiple repetition and array and i need help to find sum of each value of column in multidimensional array.
so i have this input :

```
2 -> number of tc
3 -> size of array
1 2 3
4 5 6 -> all value of array 
7 8 9
4 -> size of array
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8 -> value of array
9 0 1 2 
3 4 5 6
```

and the output will be :

```
Case#1: 12 15 18
Case#2: 18 12 16 20
```

and here is my code :

```
int n,m;
scanf("%d",&n);
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
    scanf("%d",&m);
    int o[m][m],sum[m][m];
    for(int i=1;i<=m;i++){
        for(int j=1;j<=m;j++){
        scanf("%d",&o[i][j]);
        sum[i][j]=o[i][j]+o[i+1][j+1];
        }
    }
    for(int i=1;i<=m;i++){
        for(int j=1;j<=m;j++){
        printf("Case #%d: %d ",i,sum[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Arrays start at index 0 in C. This means that your loops must always be `for(int i=0; i<m; i++)`. Check out the chapter about arrays in your favourite C programming book.

Comment: You're reusing `i` in nested loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the code :

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    int cases;
    printf ("\nCases Count? : ");
    scanf ("%d", &cases);

    for (int cid = 0; cid < cases; ++cid) {
        int size;
        printf ("\nMatrix Size : ");
        scanf ("%d", &size);
        long sum [size];        // if long has more space than int on your machine, else use long long
        for (int col = 0; col < size; ++col) // reset sums before next case
            sum[col] = 0;
        // we don't need to store matrix, as we're not re-using it
        for (int row = 0; row < size; ++row) {
            for (int col = 0; col < size; ++col) {
                int value;
                scanf ("%d", &value);
                sum[col] += value; // add the value to respective column total
            }
        }
        printf ("Case #%d: ", cid + 1);
        for (int col = 0; col < size; ++col)
            printf ("%ld ", sum[col]);
        printf ("\n");

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Warning: `scanf()` fails if you input a string instead of numbers. [scanf() usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14484498/835145). Lookup how to use `fgets()` & parse inputs to have more control.

- There is no prize for using bare minimum variable names. Use concise yet meaningful variable names, even if you're testing something.
- Enable all compiler warnings. For GCC an alias something like `alias mygcc='gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -g3 -O2 -fsanitize=address,undefined,leak -Wshadow'`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few suggestions to help you along. First, the first, second, and fourth `for` loops use the same indexing variable `i`. This will cause issues with the first `for` loop as the variable `i` is being changed by the others. I suggest you first create a program that only works with a single matrix then, once it works correctly, expand it to handle multiple matrices. This will reduce the number of `for` loops you have to manage while figuring out the indexing. Second, the `sum` array doesn't have the correct size. It looks like it should be `sum[n][m]` instead of `sum[m][m]`. Lastly, to get the output you want, you should move the output `for` loop outside of the first `for` loop. Like this:

```
int n,m;
scanf("%d",&n);
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
   ...
   for(int i=1;i<=m;i++){
      ...
   }
}
for(int i=1;i<=m;i++){
    for(int j=1;j<=m;j++){
        printf("Case #%d: %d ",i,sum[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation and correction